# Aggregating results of parallel data processing

Tags: parallel-processing, apache-camel, jms, activemq-classic, apache-servicemix

I want to process data in parallel using a cluster of ServiceMix / ActiveMQ / Camel. It seems I can achieve that by first splitting the data up, then distributing it via multiple JMS messages and an ActiveMQ network of brokers.

The part which makes it hard though is that I need to aggregate all results from all nodes in the end. I'm currently unsure how to do that. All results would have to end up on one node in the end.

So the overall flow looks like this:
(1) Retrieve data.
(2) Split it up into manageable chunks.
(3) Post chunks of data into a distributed JMS queue, via an ActiveMQ cluster.
(4) Data is processed on all nodes.

Now the part I don't know how to handle:

(5) Aggregate processed data from *all* nodes 
(6) Last processing step with the aggregated results.

```
                                                        > [Process data (node 1)] >
[Retrieve DATA] >>>[vm://]>>> [SPLIT] >>>[activemq://]>>> [Process data (node 2)] >>>[activemq://]>>> [AGGREGATE] >>>[vm://]>>> [FINALIZE DATA]
                                                        > [Process data (node 3)] >
```

How do I achieve that given that an ActiveMQ broker network happily distributes everything? Deploy the final aggregating route only on one node? Don't like it since that would create a SPOF …

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, sounds like you could use an [exclusive consumer](http://activemq.apache.org/exclusive-consumer.html) on the aggregate stage. You should be able to run that aggregate route on all nodes.

Disclaimer: Im not sure about this solution on a network of brokers. But you can probably give it a shot and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks Petter, I'll have a closer look!

Answer (score 1):

This use-case sounds like the composed message processor eip
http://camel.apache.org/composed-message-processor.html

Camel supports aggregating using the splitter only, which makes it even easier. See the link above, about the splitter only.

And with competing consumers you can have multiple nodes process the data in parallel: http://camel.apache.org/competing-consumers.html

And you should then do request/reply over JMS so the reply messages is sent back to the queue where the messages will be aggregated: http://camel.apache.org/request-reply.html

And make sure to study the information about request/reply over JMS as there is several options that can make this faster: http://camel.apache.org/jms

And for ActiveMQ broker to distribute, then you can set the brokers up in a network of brokers (NOB): http://activemq.apache.org/networks-of-brokers.html